# Using Javascript to Scroll to an class once it has been shown by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using the slideToggle function on a page to show or hide text when the user clicks a link.

The problem that I am having is that content further down the page does not immediately show when a user clicks the link because it is below the fold, so the user has to scroll down. Is is possible to use Javascript to scroll down to where the content appears when the link has been clicked?

An example of the code I am using is below:

```
<p class="show-one"><a href="#">Show one</a></p>
<p class="content-one" style="display: none;">
Hidden content goes here.
</p>
<script>
$('.expand-one').click(function(){
$('.content-one').slideToggle('slow');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should suit your needs:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.content-one').offset().top}, 1000);
```